# Simple Hello world RESTful Webservice showing 404 error

Tags: java, web-services, rest

We are trying to build a RESTful webservice to print Hello World but on running it is giving file not found error.

**java file:**

```
package com.gslabs.contact;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/Contact")
public class ContactREST {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String gethtmlcontact_info()
    {
            return "<html>"+"<title>"+"Contact-info"+"</title>"+"<body><h1>"+"Contact-Info"+"</body></h1></html>";

    }
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getXMLcontactinfo()
    {
        return "Contact info";
    }

}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>RestfulWS</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Rest Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.gslabs.contact</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Contacts Info</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Which url are you requesting?

Comment: You don't annotate the class with @WebService

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a http request such as:

```
http://domain-name2.domain-name1:port/jaxrs/rest/contact
```

where:

- `domain-name2.domain-name1` - the server on which deployed service (specify your own)
- `jaxrs` - context root (enter your own)
- `rest` - the path to the REST resources (specify your own)

And specify the resource identifier without slash:

```
@Path("contact")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the name of your project instead of jaxrs.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have "/" in contact path.
2. even if you use say `blablahhost:port/blahblah/rest/contact` with get method, your webserver is going to get confused as to which method it needs to call. So Why dont you define the path for both your get requests?